# Elasticsearchのドキュメントアップロード時にUnavailableShardsException

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearchのドキュメントのアップロード時に

```
UnavailableShardsException[[room3][1] Not enough active copies to meet write consistency of [QUORUM] (have 1, needed 2). Timeout: [1m] --- (1)
```

というエラーがでており、ドキュメントのアップロードが全くできない状態です。
ローカルマシン上のElasticsearchを再起動後、shardがunassigned状態になりました。
以下の対処法を試みたところshardはassignされましたが、
replica shardは依然としてunassignedのままで、ドキュメントのアップロードはできない状態です。
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23781013/2902531
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20010544/2902531

## 補足情報

ローカルマシンにインストールしていましたが、現在はElastic Cloudのトライアル環境で動作確認をしています

Elasticsearchのversion 2.3.5 
※ホスティング先としてAmazon Elasticsearch Serviceも考えているため2.3系を選んでいます
number_of_shards: 2
number_of_replicas: 2

### /_cat/shards

```
index shard prirep state      docs store ip           node
room3 1     p      STARTED       0  159b 10.166.19.79 instance-0000000000
room3 1     r      UNASSIGNED
room3 1     r      UNASSIGNED
room3 0     p      STARTED       0  159b 10.166.19.79 instance-0000000000
room3 0     r      UNASSIGNED
room3 0     r      UNASSIGNED
```

### /_cat/indices

```
health status index                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
red    open   .marvel-es-1-2016.12.27   1   1
yellow open   room3                     2   2          0            0       318b           318b
red    open   .marvel-es-data-1         1   1
red    open   .kibana                   1   1
red    open   my_index                  2   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

発生しているエラーは、十分な数のノードがクラスタに存在しないから発生しているように見受けられます。

クラスタの構成は何台でしょうか。レプリカ数が2なので、ノードは3台を想定した設定だと思われます。

1ノード構成でやりたいのなら、レプリカ数を 0 にすると良いでしょう。

Comment: 検証中の環境では1ノード構成です。
基本的なことが把握できていませんでした。
replica = 0 でいいんですね
ありがとうございます！

Comment: もし、私の回答で問題が解決した場合は、チェックマークをクリックして、回答を承認してください。(承認システムについてはもう知ってるよ、あえてまだ承認してないんだよ、ということでしたら、その限りでもないですが。。

Comment: すいません、一応動作確認してからと思い、解決のチェックが遅れました
replica数: 0にすることでドキュメントのアップロードが問題なくできました。
助かりました！